# React Native, node js - update object in different scripts

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state, use-context

I'm building an app in React Native,
and I am trying to understand if I need to use useState & useContext to export a user info object,
or I can just get the object from the script, change it, and it will be changed to all the other scripts.
(or if there is a better way to do it so)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Any dynamically changing value should be stored via `useState`.

Comment: So if I want to update the object I need to first change the object and the use the setUserInfo (the function to update the state from the useState) and set it to the changed object?

Comment: Yes, that works. Just don't directly modify anything without calling the appropriate set state function, as that's fundamental to React's rendering system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you update data in your component, always use `useState`.

Furthermore if you store an array or an object into your state, it's a good practice to update the array/object, and then update your state with a `spread operator` (this will create a new array/object, and fired your useEffect and UI)

Example :

If you do a simple :

```
const [stateArray, setStateArray] = useState(["foo"])
stateArray[0] = "new foo"
```

All the components that consume the `stateArray[0]` will not update and continue to display a simple `foo`

This is caused becaused this update doesn't triggered a refresh as you're array isn't update, but one of it's component (not detect by React).

If you want an update, you need to do :

```
const [stateArray, setStateArray] = useState(["foo"])
stateArray[0] = "new foo"
setStateArray([...stateArray])
```

This will create a new array, and as such, triggered a new render of your component.

And the same logic applied for object, if you only update one of its value, there will be no update, you need to create a new object :

Example :

```
const [stateObject, setStateObject] = useState({foo: "foo"})
stateObject.foo = "new foo"
setStateObject({...stateObject})
```